# Why is [a,b] notion for cross product very common in post-USSR countries and seemingly isn't used in others at all?

Tags: notation

Seems that same holds for dot product. I suppose, this is due to notions of Lie bracket and inner product in Hilbert space which are generalizations of cross and dot product and denoted in same manner in Russia as dot and cross products. But maybe someone can answer exactly?